# Access class members from anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope, anonymous

i know that i have to keep a reference to *this* inside a JS class, when i need to access class member functions. However, i am currently struggling with the following (simplified) piece of code:

```
function MySimpleClass(p, arr) {
this.proxy = p;
this.contentArray = arr;

this.doStuff = function(callback) {
    var self = this;

    // at this point this.contentArray holds data

    this.proxy.calculate(function(data) {

        // inside the anonymous function this.contentArray is undefined

        var el = self.contentArray[0]; // <-- will fail
        // do something with el

        callback.call(this, data); 
    });
}}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This code doesn't fail for me.

Comment: oh, thanks for taking a look at it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code with your class is working:

```
var c = new MySimpleClass({calculate: function(f) {f()}}, [1,2]);
c.doStuff(function(){alert("hi");})
```

I assume that your code is not working because you defined also a "self" variable in the proxy class itself. You can check that by renaming "self" in your class to something arbitrary: "selfXXX"

Answer (score 0):

What about sending the contentArray as parameter on this anonymous function, instead of sending just 'data' ?